# How to refactor four indentation levels in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of the form:

```
items = [["Wello \nWorld", "roboto.ttf", "rgb(0,0,0)"], ["StackOverflow is awesome", "roboto.ttf", "rgb(255,255,255)"]]
```

What I want to do is to go over each `list`... declare the variables `text`, `font`, `color`. After that split the text into lines if it has `\n` characters on it and then separate the lines into words to do some process with them.

Here's the code I came with to accomplish that.

```
def wrap(self, size):
    for section in sections:
        for text, font, color in section:
            for line in text.splitlines():
                for word in line:
                    pass
```

I know this function is wrong. If it's not wrong then the world is wrong. That level of indentation seems ugly and really hope you people can help me to put it in another way. Or maybe the data is wrong-structure?

**One more thing:**

I read from [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)  that:

> Flat is better than nested.

Does this apply to my question? I bet it does but I was reading a little bit on Google Groups and people tend to refer to Python Packages and Inheritance Hierarchies when referring to **Flat is better than nested**.

Comment: Typically when I see deeply nested blocks of code, the first thing to do is to see if any of those blocks can be moved to a separate function as a logical unit.  Your `wrap()` function seems to be doing a lot. The body of the `sections` loop could probably be moved to a `process_section()` function. I'd consider moving the line processing to it's own separate function as well.

Comment: The `items` you show seems to correspond to `section` in your code, so your sample data is missing a level of nesting reflected by your code. Your strings are also just encoded lists of strings, accounting for the other extra level.  Your code is going to be as nested as the data you want to parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Flat is better than nested” refers to keeping your data structures simple and avoiding nesting too many objects in another. In your case, you have a list of lists, so that’s only two levels which is not too bad. And actually, you have a list of three-tuples (yes, that “tuple” is a list but it’s still a fixed size), so it’s really not problematic at all.

And since you only have one level, you only need a single for loop to access that tuple. And then you can unpack the tuple to access those elements and further process the `text`:

```
for section in items:
    text, font, color = section
    text = text.splitlines()
    print(text, font, color)
```

This would give you:

```
['Wello ', 'World'] roboto.ttf rgb(0,0,0)
['StackOverflow is awesome'] roboto.ttf rgb(255,255,255)
```

Depending on what you want to further do with those values, you may need one more nesting to iterate through the lines of your text, but that’s not an issue, so you’re fine to do that.